# How do I use selenium to locate html elements via class with React App

Tags: reactjs, selenium, testing

I'm looking for a best way to locate elements with class names with Selenium for a React Application.

React generates a unique hash beside each class name e.g. "wrapper--**5kGNf**"

I'm considering to append a unique reference to each element in React, which would be solely done for testing purposes.

Comment: Can you share the html element details

Comment: Did you try XPATHS?

Comment: Kireeti Annamaraj - here's an example of the markup: <div class="wrapper--3r8sx"> <div class="ChatWrapper---yrEi"></div> <div class="bubbleWrapper--3HmWX"> <div class="bubbleWrapperText--1Emd1"> question text placeholder </div> </div> </div> Ramya Ramanathan - I haven't tried with XPATHS, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this was a question for my testing team at the time. We found that the React Element hashed class names don't change too often, so we could target these with CSS selectors.